# branchlock android obfuscator with jeypack compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I have bought Branchlock Obfuscator for Android, but have a problem to build my jetpack compose application

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.production.gameplay, PID: 3684
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.production.gameplay.App package com.production.gameplay: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.production.gameplay.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~NjrOjbymd-MMKw-nbIFfGQ==/com.production.gameplay-czz_YypB2XIG-Of7dzM86g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~NjrOjbymd-MMKw-nbIFfGQ==/com.production.gameplay-czz_YypB2XIG-Of7dzM86g==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6720)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
```

In JSON I wrote my activities:

```
"exclude": [
    "**/R$*",
    "**/R",
    "com/example/mycomposebranchlock/MainActivity"
    "com/example/mycomposebranchlock/ContainerActivity"
],
```

Any body tried it ? Or maybe recommend another obfuscator ? Because the support of Branchlock not so quickly and documentation is pour